# Extracting all files or change sets that changed between two labels

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to extract a list of only modified files between two labels? My ultimate objective is extract a list of files that have been modified between label2 and label3. I have been able to get TFS to output using the tf history command below; unfortunately, this command will pull up all items modified up to Label3.

`tf history /server:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs "$/source/path/main" /recursive /noprompt /format:detailed /version:"Llabel3" >> C:\temp\tfshistory.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I realized my mistake, with the command above you can get all change sets between two labels as long as you add a '~' within the /version: switch, example:

`tf history /server:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs "$/source/path/main" /recursive /noprompt /format:brief /version:"Llabel2~Llabel3" >> C:\temp\tfshistory.txt`

This will extract and create a list of all change sets between Label 2 and Label 3. You can also do the same by replacing Label3 with 'T' this will instead extract all change sets from Label2 to Latest(T).

Comment: The only shortcoming with this is that it will show you the changesets, but not the files within them. It would be nice to be able to get `tf` to output the files within the changesets.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want if you replace '/format:brief' by '/format:detailed'